# Conditional expression in Travis deployment not evaluating correctly

Tags: regex, bash, github, travis-ci

I am trying to deploy using Travis CI using the following conditional job:

```
- stage: publish
          name: Publishing components to npm registry
          script: echo "Deploying to npm..."
          before_deploy:
              - cd ./dist/components
          deploy:
              edge: true
              provider: npm
              email: XXXX
              api_key:
                  secure: vFxxLJUkMhPdb5wqs...
              on:
                  repo: ps37/components
                  tags: true
                  condition: TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^components-v\d.\d.\d$
```

But this condition `condition: TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^components-v\d.\d.\d$` is **NOT** evaluating to true!

**Can someone suggest what i am doing wrong with the condition expression?**

Answer (score 1):

If `TRAVIS_TAG` is an environment variable (like the [documentation suggests](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables)), then that variable would be referenced with: `env(TRAVIS_TAG)`

In case of a [conditional deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment-v2/conditional#examples-for-conditional-deployments), that would be a different syntax:

```
condition: $TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^components-v\d.\d.\d$
```

Comment: The above syntax doesn't seem to work. It is giving the following syntax error:
```Worker information
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 880: unexpected token `(', conditional binary operator expected
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 880: expected `)'
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 880: syntax error near `(env(T'
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 880: `  if [[ ($TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG = "ps37/vmware-cloud-director-ui-components") && (env(TRAVIS_TAG) =~ ^components-v\d.\d.\d$) && ("$TRAVIS_TAG" != "") ]]; then'```

Comment: @prudhvi I have edited the answer with another possible syntax